# How angular ngOnInit sync call methods by order?

Tags: angular

There are many functions in NgOnINit(). I want to call them by order.

```
ngOnInit(){
  A();
  B();
  C();
}
```

I don't want to use `setTimeOut()`,because I don't know the `A()` will take how much time.

Comment: They ARE called in that order.

Comment: use async and await operation https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions

Comment: You are making the assumption A, B and C methods are promise-based.